# Why the function inside <td> did not run

Tags: reactjs, function, html-table

I want to render the table data like below.

[image]

However, the second line of "Available Channel" return value is number and I want to get the string. like 0--None, 1--Web, 2--Pos....

I try to use the paymentType function to switch it but it did not work.
It seems that this function did not run at all. But I do not know why

```
<table>
 ...
 <tr>
  <td> { this.paymentType(id) } </td>
 <tr>
</table>
```

And the function I wrote likes:

```
paymentType(id){
if(id===0) { return "None"}
else if(id===1) { return "Web"}
else if(id===2) { return "Pos"}
}
```

I only got a blank line.

I changed it to arrow function, still a blank line.

```
 <table>
 ...
 <tr>
  <td> { () => this.paymentType(id) } </td>
 <tr>
</table>
```

I bind this in the constructor method, still a blank line.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.paymentType = this.paymentType.bind(this)
}
```

[image]

I wonder how to solve this problem and all your replies would be appreciated.

Comment: Please avoid posting code as screenshots.

Comment: ^ Was about to say the same. I fixed your broken images but code should be copy/pasted as [formatted code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: soory about that, I will repair it asap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call your *paymentType* function directly, don't wrap it an an arrow function declaration:

```
{ this.paymentType(payment.payment_type_id) }
```

As you had it you efectively had a function declaration in the curly braces, you were not calling your helper function.